# Boost asio synchronous write doesn't block

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, synchronous

I've wrote an application that sends information through a socket using a TCP connection. For several reasons, I'm using blocking calls but I've noticed that `boost::asio::write()` method doesn't block when the other machine (the one receiving the data) disconnects. It doesn't raise an error either.

Is this the expected behavior?

Comment: Does it return 0 bytes written?

Comment: Yes, that's what is happening.

Comment: Returning 0 bytes written, (just like a read() call returning 0 bytes read), on a BLOCKING call is the signal that the peer has closed the connection.

Comment: @MartinJames No, only a receive operation (`read`/`recv`/etc.) does that.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg - I was not sure, which is why I asked the OP what is being returned.  A blocking send() call returning 0 bytes sent must mean something:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Socket write will block when there is no room in the buffer, otherwise it will return as soon as data is in the buffer to send, not until data is delivered to the recipient. Also network stack may not detect that another side disconnected immediately, so you may or may not see error code on write. So yes, it is expected behavior.